# Symmetric $\alpha$-stable distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, levy-processes

Consider the expression appearing in the Levy-Kchinchine formula:

$$\varphi(t) = e^{ita - \sigma^2/(2t)+\int_{-\infty}^\infty [e^{itx} - 1 -itx \mathbf{1}_{|x|<1}]\,{\rm d}\nu(x)},$$ but with $a =0, \sigma = 0$ and $d\nu(x) = \frac{c}{|x|^{1+\alpha}}$, i.e.,
$$\varphi(t) = e^{\int_{-\infty}^\infty [e^{itx} - 1 -itx \mathbf{1}_{|x|<1}]\frac{c}{|x|^{1+\alpha}}\,{\rm d}x},$$

Is there a way to confirm, without going through tedious integral computations that it corresponds to the characteristic function of a symmetric $\alpha$-stable distribution?

I got lost in computations when arrived at $\Gamma(-\alpha)$ floating around.

Comment: I guess you just need to show that $\varphi(t)=\varphi(-t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. This should follow quite easily by making the substitution $x\mapsto -x$, right?

Comment: @jakobdt, actually it does not look like a real-valued function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28+%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D+%5Cleft%5Be%5E%7Bi2x%7D+-+1+-+i2x%5Cright%5D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B3%2F2%7D%7Ddx%2B%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B1%7D+%5Cleft%5Be%5E%7Bi2x%7D+-+1%5D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B3%2F2%7D%7Ddx+%2B+%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cleft%5Be%5E%7Bi2x%7D+-+1%5D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B3%2F2%7D%7Ddx%29

What could have go wrong?

Comment: @jakobdt, how would this yield $\alpha$-stability, i.e. being of the form $e^{-\gamma |t|^\alpha}$?

Comment: The Lévy density $x\mapsto c\lvert x\rvert^{-1-\alpha}$ has the correct form for $\alpha$-stability. Have a look at e.g. theorem 14.3 in Sato's "Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions".

Comment: And for the first question. Obviously the function is not real-valued, but I don't see why this is an issue? Since you are integrating over all of $\mathbb{R}$ you may write $-x$ instead of $x$ in the integral. Then rewrite this to obtain $\varphi(t)=\varphi(-t)$. What you end up using is that the Lévy density is symmetric around $0$.